# Shopify cookie policy

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

My app is being rejected because it apparently needs cookies enabled. I didn't touch any cookies myself. I use session storage but I see a bunch of cookies in my browser.

It looks to me like they are shopify cookies and I'm not sure how to proceed.

I made the app starting with the code generated by their CLI.
Anyone have any advice. The cookies I see in my. app:

koa.sess.sig

shopifyNonce.sig

shopifyNonce

koa.sess

shopify.granted_storage_access

Are any of these something that I might actually be setting myself? Don't think any of them are any third party I'm intentionally using.

Any suggestions on how I might proceed?

Comment: They said cookies isn't allowed? You need some mechanism to persist the session token so that your server can resolve it into the data. The only other method I know is to append the sessionID as a GET param to every endpoint, maybe some node module can help, but ask them if they have an alternative.

Comment: It's a requirement to use Session Tokens like JWT or something check this: https://shopify.dev/tutorials/authenticate-your-app-using-session-tokens

I've used this GitHub a couple of times, it works great. It's not with Koa, it's with Express. https://github.com/MathewsJoseph25/create-shopify-app

Comment: I'm also having this issue @Chris ... the only cookie I have is `token` which isn't a third party cookie and is simply a JWT token. It's very annoying because I haven't had any issues while developing.

Comment: Acidic9 I think the first layer of Shopify approval is fubar. I talked my client into not maintaining logins in the first app version. So a customer has to login again if they refresh the page.

If that won't work then my recommendation is to do anything you can to get past the first approval round. There's a second round of approval and the devs you work with there seem to have a stronger tech background and you can probably work with them to build a viable solution.

That first round is super strict and working with really poor support